# activemq broker name

Tags: activemq-classic

I am trying to build a generic activemq command line to tool for monitoring purposes.
It uses JMX connection to get the information.
To get the information i need the broker name to be used in the ObjectName constructor.
(e.g ObjectName activeMQ = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Queue,Destination=" + queueName);)

I am unable to run it if the broker name is not known.

Is there a way i can determine the activemq broker name programmatically?

Thanks and Regards,
Arijit Bose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a wildcard in the JMS query to get all brokers and then go from there.